# Wordpress paginate_links select option

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to output a select option for the wordpress pagination array - `paginate_links`

Current settings:

```
$links = paginate_links( array(
    'base'     => $pagenum_link,
    'format'   => $format,
    'total'    => $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages,
    'current'  => $paged,
    'mid_size' => 3,
    'add_args' => array_map( 'urlencode', $query_args ),
    'prev_text' => __( '&larr; Previous', 'm_chamber' ),
    'next_text' => __( 'Next &rarr;', 'm_chamber' ),
    'type'      => 'array'
) );
```

Then:

```
<select>
    <?php
foreach ( $links as $pgl ) {
    echo '<option>'.$pgl.'</option>';
}
    ?>
</select>
```

However, i am having a hard time trying to get the next button and the previous button to stay out of the select option. Secondly, trying to place the link within the `value` element of the select option.

**Expected Output:**

```
<<NEXT [SELECT] PREV>>
```

**Within the select**

```
<option value="link/page1">Page 1</option>
<option value="link/page2">Page 2</option>
```

etc..

Is there anyway possible

Comment: Not sure if it's what you mean but prev and next links always comes as first and last index in array, so you can remove them when needed. With ``array_shift`` and ``array_pop``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an additional plugin for myself that generates either a

1. Normal pagination `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
2. Select option `<<NEXT [SELECT] PREV>>`

Change the config.php file and call the function (rename it if you would like)

```
<?php jagmit_paging_nav(); ?>
```

https://github.com/jagmitg/Wordpress-Select-Pagination

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to functions.php in your theme file ->

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'my_pagination' ) ) :
function my_pagination() {
    global $wp_query;

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
}
endif;
```

Now you can call the function like as ->

```
<?php my_pagination(); ?>
```

I have use this code & it's working. See reference on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Comment: Also you can try by http://www.scratchinginfo.net/how-to-create-wordpress-pagination-without-a-plugin/  or http://adambalee.com/how-to-add-pagination-to-your-wordpress-blog-without-a-plugin/